# msbuild for linux project: adding libraries located on WSL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have an MSbuild-for-Linux project (vs studio project template) which has grown big and is successfully deployed using a remote linux system.
I switched to WSL2 (Ubuntu 22.04) using "WSL2 GCC Toolset" - This already works fine for smaller projects - but when the project has library includes, problems arise. Needed libs are located in:`/usr/lib..`
On the fine-working remote-linux, a valid library include path is like:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2main.a
```

..so I need to change the paths for WSL2. I installed all relevant packages and proved the location of the libraries on the WSL filesystem - using the explorer, they are all shown, e.g. take this valid win-explorer path:

```
\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\usr\lib\x86_64-linux-gnu\libSDL2main.a
```

so in visual studio linker settings -> Input -> Additional Dependencies, tried:

```
\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\usr\lib\x86_64-linux-gnu\libSDL2main.a // ..not found - results in eleminating backslashes 

\\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu\\usr\\lib\\x86_64-linux-gnu\\libSDL2main.a // ..not found

\\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2main.a // ..not found
```

.. and some more tries

I can't figure out how to specifiy the WSL lib path correctly, can you ?